# Re-using a range for iteration

Tags: rust

Im trying to understand how to use ranges with iterators. If I declare a range and use it with an iterator, is it possible to re-use that range with another iterator?
For example this does not compile:

```rust
fn main() {
    let smallr = 0..10;
    for i in smallr {
        println!("value is {}", i);
    }

    //let smallr = 0..15;  re-defining smallr will work!
    let sum  = smallr.fold(0, |sum, x| sum + x);
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range type `Range` does not implement `Copy`. Therefor using a range in a for loop will consume it. If you want to create a copy of a range, you can use `.clone()`:

```
for i in smallr.clone() {
    println!("value is {}", i);
}
```

Note that this might cause confusing behavior when used on a mutable range (which afaik is the reason why `Range` does not implement `Copy`). A range is also an iterator at the same time. If you only partially consume the iterator and then clone it, You get a clone of the partially consumed iterator.

As an example of the pitfall:

```
fn main() {
    let mut smallr = 0..10;

    println!("first: {:?}", smallr.next());
    for i in smallr.clone() {
        println!("value is {}", i);
    }
}
```

prints

```
first: Some(0)
value is 1
value is 2
value is 3
value is 4
value is 5
value is 6
value is 7
value is 8
value is 9
```

which shows that the first value of the range is not part of the cloned iterator.