# Why doesn't ops::Range<T> implement Copy, even if T is Copy?

Tags: rust

Recently, I wanted to write a type holding parameters for a 3D projection:

```
use std::ops::Range;

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct CamProj {
    /// Near and far plane
    proj_range: Range<f32>,
    /// Field of view
    fov: cgmath::Rad<f32>,     // `Rad` derives `Copy`
    /// Width divided by height
    aspect_ratio: f32,       
}
```

However, I got this error:

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
 --> <anon>:3:21
  |
3 |     #[derive(Clone, Copy)]
  |                     ^^^^
...
6 |         proj_range: Range<f32>,
  |         ---------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
```

So apparently, `Range<T>` never implements `Copy`, even if `T` is `Copy`, like `f32` is. **Why is that?** I thought a `Range<T>` would just be a pair of `T`s? So it surely could implement `Copy`?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question before... but of course cannot find it again. The closest potential duplicate I found was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045637/re-using-a-range-for-iteration. I seem to recall it was not implemented because there were cases where it could be confusing: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because `Range<T>` is often used as an iterator, and having iterators be `Copy` [was discovered to be a footgun](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045). [One specific example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21809#issuecomment-72372377) had to do with thinking that an iterator was advanced, when in reality it was a copy that was advanced:

```
for x in it {  // a *copy* of the iterator is used here
    // ..
}

match it.next() {  // the original iterator is used here
    // ..
}
```

[Another example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045):

```
fn main() {
    let stream = "Hello, world!".chars().cycle();
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let chunk: String = stream.take(3).collect();
        println!("{}", chunk);
    }
}
```

And another that prompted a question: [Using the same iterator multiple times in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23969191/155423)

It was believed that having iterators be explicitly copied via `clone` helped prevent these cases

---

Specifically re-adding `Copy` to `Range` [was proposed and rejected](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21846). A potential workaround was suggested:

> Range fields are public, you can repack them into a copyable tuple (or equivalent) at the constructor/function boundary

See also:

- [Why are iterators not copyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32324251/155423)
- [Re-using a range for iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31045637/155423)