# How to re-use a Range multiple times without cloning it?

Tags: loops, for-loop, rust, iterator, range

I have some working code to sum a `Range` and then use it again later in a `for` loop. Is it possible to make the code below work without having to clone the `Range`?

```
let range = 0..10;
let sum = range.clone().sum::<i8>();
println!("{}", sum);

for data in range.step_by(2).enumerate() {
   println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in your question why you want to avoid cloning the Range?

Comment: I'm new with Rust and its feel weird to clone it first.

Comment: Note that `clone` is expensive only when the underlying data is large and/or heap-allocated, as is the case when cloning a large vector, which must both allocate and clone each element. But cloning a `Range`, which is basically a couple of stack (or register) allocated integers is "zero cost", meaning it costs the same as just writing the same range twice. In other words, don't be afraid to clone where needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Range<T>` is an iterator. Rust iterators are usually:

- One shot. You can iterate once, and only once. Iterating modifies the iterator, and there is no way to "go back" or to reset them. If you want to iterate twice, you have to clone them, or create another iterator somehow.
- Cheap. Iterators rarely store any data. In particular, `Range<T>` only stores its two bounds, not the entire range of numbers. `0..10` is therefore just a pair of integers, which is really cheap to clone.
- Not `Copy`, even when their underlying data is. This is why you need the explicit `clone`, and this is because a `Copy` iterator would be unintuitive to use.

  See also:

  - [Why doesn't ops::Range implement Copy, even if T is Copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416914/why-doesnt-opsranget-implement-copy-even-if-t-is-copy)
  - GitHub: [Implicitly copyable iterators are mega confusing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045)
  - GitHub: [`impl Copy for Range<Idx> where Idx: Copy`?](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48649)
  - Reddit: [Why does std::ops::Range not derive `Copy`?](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/47uqgj/why_does_stdopsrange_not_derive_copy/)

Comment: I see, on call sum its iterate once and cannot be re-use. thats why need clone there. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [@mcarton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623168/2766908) for a general explanation, but if you're just learning Rust and experimenting with toy examples then simpler version of your code would be to just declare the `Range` twice:

```rust
fn main() {
    let sum: i32 = (0..10).sum();
    println!("{}", sum);
    
    for data in (0..10).step_by(2).enumerate() {
        println!("{:?}", data);
    }
}
```

If you were writing a function that accepted the `Range` as an argument then you would have to clone (or be creative in consolidating both loops):

```rust
fn fun(mut range: Range<i32>) {
    let sum: i32 = range.clone().sum();
    println!("{}", sum);
    
    for data in range.step_by(2).enumerate() {
        println!("{:?}", data);
    }
}
```

Regardless, cloning a `Range` is not a big deal because it's only two integers:

```rust
pub struct Range<Idx> {
    pub start: Idx,
    pub end: Idx,
}
```

So whether you're cloning a `0..10` or a `0..1000000` they're all the same size and the clone operation will be fast and cheap.

Comment: "the idiomatic version of your code would be to just declare the `Range` twice" I disagree completely. Repeating magical constants is never a good solution.

Comment: I think OP is just learning Rust by experimenting with toy examples. There's no actual requirement that the ranges have to be the same. I've updated my answer to make these assumptions clear.